# Error while trying to run executable Jar in cmd

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I know there are a few other similar questions to this, but the solutions don't seem to work. (I have read about a dozen stack-overflow forums)

Here is that I tried doing in CMD:

```
C:\Users\warre>java -jar C:\Users\warre\OneDrive\Desktop\MirrorUserInput.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: usefulTools/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

C:\Users\warre>javac -version
javac 14

C:\Users\warre>java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

[Here is my source code.](https://github.com/NeuralyzerGaming/ClickingAndTypingMirror/tree/master/usefulTools/src/usefulTools)

I understand that some of the issues may arise from the discrepancy between JDK and JRE but I got confused when I tried to understand that complexity (I know the general difference between the two, and have read a few articles, but get confused exactly why it is causing an issue in eclipse.)

I used eclipse to export this. I used all the default settings. I can send screenshots of this information if requested.

Comment: your compiler is higher version than runtime

Comment: Thanks Erwin - do you know how to update my runtime to make it match my compiler?

Comment: uninstall then reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The discrepancy occurs when version of JDK is higher than the JRE version.

The reported major numbers are:

```
Java SE 14 = 58,
Java SE 13 = 57,
Java SE 12 = 56,
Java SE 11 = 55,
Java SE 10 = 54,
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Based on the error message I can say for sure that your eclipse JDK version is set as Java 13 and the JRE version of your machine is 8.

You have two solutions. One solution maybe to upgrade your JRE to 13 at least. Or go to the eclipse Java compiler option and decrease the JDK version to JDK 8.

In Eclipse, go to menu command Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and then set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.8.

Comment: Thanks Karim for the help! I would rather update my local JRE and bring it up to current - how do I go about doing that? I’m slightly confused because when I first downloaded java I always choose the most current version... maybe I need to re-download the JRE? (I started programming on this current PC when quarantine started so I thought it was up to date)

Comment: You have to download jdk 13 from Oracle website. Then you need to set the bin folder of the downloaded jdk to your path variable. You can do this based on your operating system. Make sure to replace the path to the old jdk/bin folder for avoiding conflict.

Comment: Also, please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as correct if you find it helpful and correct. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t have 15 rep - how do I upvote your comment?

Comment: You can definitely upvote the ANSWER and mark it as resolved afaik.

Comment: Alright - I tried to upvote - won't work - but I at least marked it as correct.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Hopefully you have a good stack overflow journey :-)

Comment: No, Thank you! :)